# Install KOMA script in Ubuntu-12.04 LTS

Tags: biblatex, koma-script, ubuntu

I apologize for this question, but I tried to install `KOMA-script` in my machine, the operating system is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I tried to install from the Makefile after I got the file koma-script.zip. I also have all the files for the bibliography in the `biblatex` package and I could not compile correctly the thesis style from Universitaet Bonn, it uses the `koma-script` and I think the problem is with the script. I really will appreciate any help from you about.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Remove all that and install the `koma-script.tds.zip` from [this link](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/install/macros/latex/contrib).  `.tds.zip` files are really easy to install: just unzip them at the base of your `texmf` tree, which can be found with `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMF`  (or just do `unzip koma-script.tds.zip -d ~/texmf/` if you just want a 'personal' install on a single-user system).

Comment: I think the `KOMA-script` is also contained in the package `texlive-latex-recommended`, so the easy option would be to install that package (`sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-recommended`)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, the script now is working properly!

Comment: Hi, I use the first comment to install the koma script, I mean, after I got the koma-script.tds.zip, I follow:unzip koma-script.tds.zip -d ~/texmf/. With the directories I run the steps to have the koma-script working properly

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is could be solved with a software update.