# Changing section and subsection format not affecting headmark

Tags: titlesec, scrlayer-scrpage

I want to have the following document structure:

Exercise 1   %sections
    a)        %subsections
    b)
Exercise 2

I found the following solution to put the section title before the numbering and changing the subsection number format:

```
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\alph{subsection})}
\titleformat{\section}[runin]{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{#1\ \thesection\\}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{#1\ \thesubsection\\}
```

Btw: Can I shift the whole subsection part to the right?

However I am using  the package scrlayer-scrpage to define a footer and a header. In the inner footer a text should display the exercise number, which is the section number. So I used \headmark for this but it always displays the  number before the term "Exercise". How can I change it?

This is a minimal example:

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,headsepline,footsepline,abstracton,notitlepage]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\alph{subsection})}

\titleformat{\section}[runin]{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0pt}
{#1\ \thesection\\}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{}{0pt}
{#1\ \thesubsection\\}

\automark{section}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{Author}
\ohead{\today}

\ifoot{\headmark}
\cfoot{Course xxx }
\ofoot{\pagemark}

\author{Chuck Norris}
\date{\today}

\title{xxx - Sheet 42}

\begin{document}


\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
    asdfahadga
\end{abstract}

\newpage

\section{Exercise}
tsestsfadf
\newpage
\subsection{Part }
asdf
\newpage
\section{Exercise}
\subsection{Part}
asdfadga
\subsection{Part}
\newpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your issue may be related to [Incompatibilities between KOMA-Script and titlesec](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36299/106162)

Comment: Actually I don't have any problems compiling this example so O don't experience any incompatibilities. It's just the format which i want to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the order of section text and number in the page header or footer redefine `\sectionmark`

```
\renewcommand*\sectionmark[1]{%
  \markright{#1 \ifnumbered{section}{\sectionmarkformat}{}}%
}
\renewcommand*\sectionmarkformat{\thesection}
```

---

But note that it is not recommended to use `titlesec` together with a KOMA-Script class. You can redefine `\sectionlinesformat` to change the order of text and number for section and subsection headings:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{section}{\@hangfrom{\hskip #2}{#4 #3}}{%
    \ifstr{#1}{subsection}{\@hangfrom{\hskip #2}{#4 #3}}{%
      \@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{#4}}}%
}
\makeatother
```

To redefine the format of the numbers in section and subsection headings use

```
\renewcommand*\sectionformat{\thesection}
\renewcommand*\subsectionformat{\thesubsection)}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\alph{subsection}}
```

To change or set the font of the section and subsection headings use

```
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\setkomafont{section}{\Large}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\large}
```

To change the order of section text and number in the page header or footer redefine `\sectionmark` as suggested above

```
\renewcommand*\sectionmark[1]{%
  \markright{#1 \ifnumbered{section}{\sectionmarkformat}{}}%
}
\renewcommand*\sectionmarkformat{\sectionformat}
```

The last line ensures that the section number in the page header/footer is formatted in the same way as in the section heading.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[
  fontsize=10pt,
  headsepline,
  footsepline,
  abstract=on
]{scrartcl}[2015/10/03]
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{section}{\@hangfrom{\hskip #2}{#4 #3}}{%
    \ifstr{#1}{subsection}{\@hangfrom{\hskip #2}{#4 #3}}{%
      \@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{#4}}}%
}
\makeatother
\renewcommand*\sectionformat{\thesection}
\renewcommand*\subsectionformat{\thesubsection)}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\alph{subsection}}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\setkomafont{section}{\Large}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\large}

\renewcommand*\sectionmark[1]{%
  \markright{#1 \ifnumbered{section}{\sectionmarkformat}{}}%
}
\renewcommand*\sectionmarkformat{\sectionformat}

\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{Author}
\ohead{\today}

\ifoot{\rightmark}
\cfoot{Course xxx }
\ofoot{\pagemark}

\author{Chuck Norris}
\date{\today}
\title{xxx - Sheet 42}

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\clearpage
\section{Exercise}
\lipsum
\subsection{Part}
\lipsum[2]
\section{Exercise}
\subsection{Part}
\lipsum[3]
\subsection{Part}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

---

To indent the whole subsection part you could use `addmargin`.

```
 \documentclass[
  fontsize=10pt,
  headsepline,
  footsepline,
  abstract=on
]{scrartcl}[2015/10/03]
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\newcommand*\exercisepartindent{20pt}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  afterskip=.5\baselineskip
]{section}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-.5\baselineskip,
  afterskip=1sp,
  indent=\exercisepartindent
]{subsection}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{section}{\@hangfrom{\hskip #2}{#4 #3}}{%
    \ifstr{#1}{subsection}{\@hangfrom{\hskip #2}{#4 #3}}{%
      \@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{#4}}}%
}
\makeatother
\renewcommand*\sectionformat{\thesection}
\renewcommand*\subsectionformat{\thesubsection)}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\alph{subsection}}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\setkomafont{section}{\Large}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\large}

\automark{section}
\renewcommand*\sectionmark[1]{%
  \markright{#1 \ifnumbered{section}{\sectionmarkformat}{}}%
}
\renewcommand*\sectionmarkformat{\sectionformat}

\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{Author}
\ohead{\today}

\ifoot{\rightmark}
\cfoot{Course xxx }
\ofoot{\pagemark}

\author{Chuck Norris}
\date{\today}
\title{xxx - Sheet 42}

\newenvironment{exercisepart}{%
  \subsection{Part}
  \begin{addmargin}[\exercisepartindent]{0cm}%
}{%
  \end{addmargin}
}

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\clearpage
\section{Exercise}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{exercisepart}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{exercisepart}
\section{Exercise}
\begin{exercisepart}
  \lipsum[3]
\end{exercisepart}
\begin{exercisepart}
  \lipsum
\end{exercisepart}
\end{document}
```

Result

[image]

---

With a KOMA-Script Version **older than 3.19** (current is 3.21) you have to use `titlesec` to change the order of the section number and text. Note that this is **not recommended for version 3.19 or newer** (see above).

```
\documentclass[
  fontsize=10pt,
  headsepline,
  footsepline,
  abstract=on
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\newcommand*\exercisepartindent{20pt}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\usekomafont{disposition}\usekomafont{section}}{}{0pt}{#1\ \sectionformat}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\usekomafont{disposition}\usekomafont{section}}{}{0pt}{#1\ \subsectionformat}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{.5\baselineskip}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{\exercisepartindent}{.5\baselineskip}{0pt}


\def\sectionformat{\thesection}
\def\subsectionformat{\thesubsection}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\alph{subsection}}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\setkomafont{section}{\Large}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\large}

\automark{section}
\renewcommand*\sectionmark[1]{%
  \markright{#1 \ifnumbered{section}{\sectionmarkformat}{}}%
}
\renewcommand*\sectionmarkformat{\sectionformat}

\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{Author}
\ohead{\today}

\ifoot{\rightmark}
\cfoot{Course xxx }
\ofoot{\pagemark}

\author{Chuck Norris}
\date{\today}
\title{xxx - Sheet 42}

\newenvironment{exercisepart}{%
  \subsection{Part}
  \begin{addmargin}[\exercisepartindent]{0cm}%
}{%
  \end{addmargin}
}

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\clearpage
\section{Exercise}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{exercisepart}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{exercisepart}
\section{Exercise}
\begin{exercisepart}
  \lipsum[3]
\end{exercisepart}
\begin{exercisepart}
  \lipsum
\end{exercisepart}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! The results look exactly like I want, but I don't understand how you arrived there. And if I just copy and paste your code it won't compile and throws errors:
line 12: \sectionlinesformat undefined. \renewcommand\sectionlinesformat
line 18: \sectionformat undefined. \renewcommand*\sectionformat
line 19: \subsectionformat undefined. \renewcommand*\subsectionformat

Comment: Which KOMA-Script Version do you use? `\sectionlinesformat` was introduced in version 3.19, `\sectionformat` is used since version 3.17 (and defined since 3.15). Current KOMA-Script version is 3.21. Can you update?

Comment: How can I check the version of KOMA-script? I am running  everything on raspbian and the command tlmgr info koma-script is not working

Comment: Have a look in the log file or add `\KOMAScriptVersion` to the document.

Comment: I have added a suggestion for KOMA-Script versions older than 3.19.

Comment: According to my log file I am using KOMA-script version 3.12,  so that's obviously the problem.  How can I update the KOMA-script script?  I tried it with "sudo apt-get install - - reinstall texlive-base".  I am running Raspbian...

Comment: I don't know anything about Raspbian. It seems that Raspbian uses an old TeXLive Version (see your log file). KOMA-Script Version 3.12 was released in Dezember 2013. But I have added a suggestion at the end of my answer that should work with KOMA 3.12.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I managed to install a new KOMA version by following the instuctions of the first comment on this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134941/install-koma-script-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts 
Then your code worked perfectly fine